# Win32::Console and STDOUT

Tags: perl, winapi, console, stdout

```
package MY_TEST;
use warnings;
use strict;
use Win32::Console;

my $out = Win32::Console->new( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

sub test_print {
    $out->Write( "printed with 'Write'\n" );
    print( "printed with 'print'\n" );
}
```

When I call this package with this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.0;
use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use MY_TEST;

say 'Before "test_print"';
MY_TEST::test_print;
say 'After "test_print"';
```

the output looks like this

```
Before "test_print"
printed with 'Write'
printed with 'print'
After "test_print"
```

But when I comment the `Write` line out

```
# $out->Write( "printed with 'Write'\n" );
```

the output is empty.

Why does removing the `Write` line prevent printing the `print` lines?

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to mix the two methods?

Comment: I am using `Win32::Console::ANSI` so the most time I can use `print` but to determine the cursor position I need a `Win32::Console->new( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE )` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but it could be related to needing to flush the buffer.  `Write()` might do it while `print()` naturally will not.

Comment: Why does `Flush` have an influence on the output - the docu says that `Flush` flushes the console input buffer?

Comment: And why does both work: flushing before the `print` and flushing after the `print`?

Comment: From my experience in any i/o task, flush usually applies to output.  Not sure why the documentation indicates it is specific to input.  I believe flushing before and after is similar to why having Write before or after works: both commands get queued in some manner and the flushing is performed after regardless.  This is all speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the reason, but I can replicate the behavior under Windows XP SP3 with ActiveState's perl 5.16.3.

On a hunch, I made the following change in `MY_TEST.pm`:

```
my $out;

sub test_print {
    $out ||= Win32::Console->new( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
#    $out->Write( "printed with 'Write'\n" );
    print( "printed with 'print'\n" );
}
```

And I got the output:

```
Before "test_print"
printed with 'print'
After "test_print"
```

Interesting …

This has something to do with the which phase of the execution of the script the handle gets assigned/resolved, but I can't quite put my finger on it right now.