# Loading package with Win32::Console - no output

Tags: perl, winapi, console, stdout

why do I get no output, when I load this package (WinXP SP3, Strawberry Perl 5.18.1)?

```
package MY_TEST;
use warnings;
use strict;
use Win32::Console;

my $output;
$output ||= Win32::Console->new( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

1;
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.0;
use MY_TEST;

say 'Hello World';
```

No output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Win32::Console and STDOUT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387181/win32console-and-stdout)

Comment: `my $output; $output ||= ...`  should be shortened to `my $output = ...`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
package MY_TEST;
use warnings;
use strict;
use Win32::Console;

my $output = Win32::Console->new( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
$output->{handle} = undef;

1;
```

I suppose the problem is related to this [Bug #33513](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=33513).